# hide button using siblings from nested table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have table, displaying Add and remove button in one of column; and got nested table inside this table holding confirm button.... I want to hide Add button and show remove button when user click on confirm using jQuery siblings function...

Many Thanks

### jQuery function

```
  $("#ElementTable").on("click", ".k1-grid-confirm", function () {

        var elementRecordId = $(this).data("id");

        alert("elementRecordId " + elementRecordId);

        // need help here....
        //$(".NastedElementTable").hide();

        //$(this).parent().siblings(".k1-grid-Remove").show();


        }
    });
```

### html

```
<div class="CustomTableBlock_01">
                <table class="customTable_01" id="ElementTable">
                 <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="SC_a1">
                                Element
                            </th>

                            <th class="SC_a2">
                                Marking-Scheme
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                 </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="SC_a1"> Practical </td>

                            <td class="SC_a2">
                                <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-Add ComponentScheme_Add" data-id="1" name="button" value="Add">
                                <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-Remove Element_Remove" data-id="1" name="button" value="Remove">


                                <table class="NastedElementTable" style="display: none;">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="N_th">Mark Scheme Title</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Available-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Pass-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Merit-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Distinction-Mark</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_Title_Element" id="1_DM" class="ElementDistinctionMark k-grid-input k-textbox_3">  </td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_AvailableMark_Element" id="1_AM" class="ElementAvailableMarks k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_PassMark_Element" id="1_PM" class="ElementPassMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_MeritMark_Element" id="1_MM" class="ElementMeritMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_DistinctionMark_Element" id="1_DM" class="ElementDistinctionMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>

                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="5" class="NastedElementTableOptTd">
                                                <div class="NastedElementTableOptBlock">
                                                    <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-confirm Element_confirm" data-id="1" name="button" value="Confirm">
                                                    <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-cancel Element_cancel" data-id="1" name="button" value="Cancel">      
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>



                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="SC_a1"> Essay </td>

                            <td class="SC_a2">
                                <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-Add ComponentScheme_Add" data-id="2" name="button" value="Add">
                                <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-Remove Element_Remove" data-id="2" name="button" value="Remove">


                                <table class="NastedElementTable" style="display: none;">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="N_th">Mark Scheme Title</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Available-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Pass-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Merit-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Distinction-Mark</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_Title_Element" id="2_DM" class="ElementDistinctionMark k-grid-input k-textbox_3">  </td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_AvailableMark_Element" id="2_AM" class="ElementAvailableMarks k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_PassMark_Element" id="2_PM" class="ElementPassMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_MeritMark_Element" id="2_MM" class="ElementMeritMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_DistinctionMark_Element" id="2_DM" class="ElementDistinctionMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>

                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="5" class="NastedElementTableOptTd">
                                                <div class="NastedElementTableOptBlock">
                                                    <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-confirm Element_confirm" data-id="2" name="button" value="Confirm">
                                                    <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-cancel Element_cancel" data-id="2" name="button" value="Cancel">      
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>



                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="SC_a1"> Performance </td>

                            <td class="SC_a2">
                                <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-Add ComponentScheme_Add" data-id="3" name="button" value="Add">
                                <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-Remove Element_Remove" data-id="3" name="button" value="Remove">


                                <table class="NastedElementTable" style="display: none;">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="N_th">Mark Scheme Title</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Available-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Pass-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Merit-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Distinction-Mark</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_Title_Element" id="3_DM" class="ElementDistinctionMark k-grid-input k-textbox_3">  </td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_AvailableMark_Element" id="3_AM" class="ElementAvailableMarks k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_PassMark_Element" id="3_PM" class="ElementPassMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_MeritMark_Element" id="3_MM" class="ElementMeritMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_DistinctionMark_Element" id="3_DM" class="ElementDistinctionMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>

                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="5" class="NastedElementTableOptTd">
                                                <div class="NastedElementTableOptBlock">
                                                    <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-confirm Element_confirm" data-id="3" name="button" value="Confirm">
                                                    <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-cancel Element_cancel" data-id="3" name="button" value="Cancel">      
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>



                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="SC_a1"> E1 </td>

                            <td class="SC_a2">
                                <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-Add ComponentScheme_Add" data-id="4" name="button" value="Add">
                                <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-Remove Element_Remove" data-id="4" name="button" value="Remove">


                                <table class="NastedElementTable" style="display: none;">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="N_th">Mark Scheme Title</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Available-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Pass-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Merit-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Distinction-Mark</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_Title_Element" id="4_DM" class="ElementDistinctionMark k-grid-input k-textbox_3">  </td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_AvailableMark_Element" id="4_AM" class="ElementAvailableMarks k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_PassMark_Element" id="4_PM" class="ElementPassMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_MeritMark_Element" id="4_MM" class="ElementMeritMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_DistinctionMark_Element" id="4_DM" class="ElementDistinctionMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>

                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="5" class="NastedElementTableOptTd">
                                                <div class="NastedElementTableOptBlock">
                                                    <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-confirm Element_confirm" data-id="4" name="button" value="Confirm">
                                                    <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-cancel Element_cancel" data-id="4" name="button" value="Cancel">      
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>



                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="SC_a1"> E2 </td>

                            <td class="SC_a2">
                                <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-Add ComponentScheme_Add" data-id="5" name="button" value="Add">
                                <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-Remove Element_Remove" data-id="5" name="button" value="Remove">


                                <table class="NastedElementTable" style="display: none;">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="N_th">Mark Scheme Title</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Available-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Pass-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Merit-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Distinction-Mark</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_Title_Element" id="5_DM" class="ElementDistinctionMark k-grid-input k-textbox_3">  </td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_AvailableMark_Element" id="5_AM" class="ElementAvailableMarks k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_PassMark_Element" id="5_PM" class="ElementPassMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_MeritMark_Element" id="5_MM" class="ElementMeritMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_DistinctionMark_Element" id="5_DM" class="ElementDistinctionMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>

                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="5" class="NastedElementTableOptTd">
                                                <div class="NastedElementTableOptBlock">
                                                    <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-confirm Element_confirm" data-id="5" name="button" value="Confirm">
                                                    <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-cancel Element_cancel" data-id="5" name="button" value="Cancel">      
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>



                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="SC_a1"> E3 </td>

                            <td class="SC_a2">
                                <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-Add ComponentScheme_Add" data-id="6" name="button" value="Add">
                                <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-Remove Element_Remove" data-id="6" name="button" value="Remove">


                                <table class="NastedElementTable" style="display: none;">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="N_th">Mark Scheme Title</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Available-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Pass-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Merit-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Distinction-Mark</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_Title_Element" id="6_DM" class="ElementDistinctionMark k-grid-input k-textbox_3">  </td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_AvailableMark_Element" id="6_AM" class="ElementAvailableMarks k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_PassMark_Element" id="6_PM" class="ElementPassMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_MeritMark_Element" id="6_MM" class="ElementMeritMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_DistinctionMark_Element" id="6_DM" class="ElementDistinctionMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>

                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="5" class="NastedElementTableOptTd">
                                                <div class="NastedElementTableOptBlock">
                                                    <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-confirm Element_confirm" data-id="6" name="button" value="Confirm">
                                                    <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-cancel Element_cancel" data-id="6" name="button" value="Cancel">      
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>



                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="SC_a1"> E4 </td>

                            <td class="SC_a2">
                                <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-Add ComponentScheme_Add" data-id="7" name="button" value="Add">
                                <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-Remove Element_Remove" data-id="7" name="button" value="Remove">


                                <table class="NastedElementTable" style="display: none;">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="N_th">Mark Scheme Title</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Available-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Pass-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Merit-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Distinction-Mark</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_Title_Element" id="7_DM" class="ElementDistinctionMark k-grid-input k-textbox_3">  </td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_AvailableMark_Element" id="7_AM" class="ElementAvailableMarks k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_PassMark_Element" id="7_PM" class="ElementPassMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_MeritMark_Element" id="7_MM" class="ElementMeritMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_DistinctionMark_Element" id="7_DM" class="ElementDistinctionMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>

                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="5" class="NastedElementTableOptTd">
                                                <div class="NastedElementTableOptBlock">
                                                    <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-confirm Element_confirm" data-id="7" name="button" value="Confirm">
                                                    <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-cancel Element_cancel" data-id="7" name="button" value="Cancel">      
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>



                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="SC_a1"> E5 </td>

                            <td class="SC_a2">
                                <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-Add ComponentScheme_Add" data-id="8" name="button" value="Add">
                                <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-Remove Element_Remove" data-id="8" name="button" value="Remove">


                                <table class="NastedElementTable" style="display: none;">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="N_th">Mark Scheme Title</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Available-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Pass-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Merit-Mark</th>
                                            <th class="N_th">Distinction-Mark</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_Title_Element" id="8_DM" class="ElementDistinctionMark k-grid-input k-textbox_3">  </td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_AvailableMark_Element" id="8_AM" class="ElementAvailableMarks k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_PassMark_Element" id="8_PM" class="ElementPassMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_MeritMark_Element" id="8_MM" class="ElementMeritMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>
                                            <td class="N_td"><input type="text" value="" name="Input_DistinctionMark_Element" id="8_DM" class="ElementDistinctionMark k-grid-input k-textbox_4"></td>

                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="5" class="NastedElementTableOptTd">
                                                <div class="NastedElementTableOptBlock">
                                                    <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-confirm Element_confirm" data-id="8" name="button" value="Confirm">
                                                    <input type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k1-grid-cancel Element_cancel" data-id="8" name="button" value="Cancel">      
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>



                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
             </div>
```

Comment: can you post the rendered html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
$(this).closest('table').siblings('.k1-grid-Add').hide();//hide add button
$(this).closest('table').siblings('.k1-grid-Remove').show();//showremove button
```